# PHP form that collects email and website address

Tags: php, security

I have built the following form that collects both email addresses and website urls from people. In the database the email and website url are set to be unique so a person cannot enter the same email and website twice.

However being new to PHP I want to double check that the form does not contain any serious problems that could allow a person to do something malicious with the form and/or has validation issues that could be exploited. Also because I want to hide the form on postback BUT show it again for errors, I have ended up duplicating the form which isn't ideal but not a big deal in this circumstance as it's just a quick form. The main factor is making sure the validation is pretty strong and no holes exist in terms of server/sql attacks in the form.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // DATABASE CONNECTION HERE

    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['EMAIL']);
    $website = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['WEBSITE']);

    if ( $email == '' || $website == '' || !filter_var($website, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
    {
        echo '<p style="color:red;">You must fill out all fields correctly and duplicate emails/websites are not permitted!</p>';

    ?>
        <form action="./" method="post">

            <label for="EMAIL">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL" required>
            <label for="WEBSITE">Website URL</label>
            <input type="url" value="" name="WEBSITE" id="WEBSITE" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Join" name="join">

        </form>

    <?php

    }
    else
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO list VALUES (NULL, '$email','$website')";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        echo '<p>THANKS!</p>';
    }
}
else
{

?>

<form action="./" method="post">

    <label for="EMAIL">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL" required>
    <label for="WEBSITE">Website URL</label>
    <input type="url" value="" name="WEBSITE" id="WEBSITE" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe">

</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You probably want to post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Oh and brace yourself as I'm sure someone will tell you to stop using the old mysql_ functions.

Comment: If you are serious about security you should ditch the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and switch to prepared statements in mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the values using [these validation filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php). You can find some instructions [for this here](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php).

To prevent cross site scripting and similar attack vectors you should not insert the email or url into the database unless it has been validated.

Comment: Well the values don't inserted unless they are valid emails and urls and the columns are set to be unique.

Comment: He *IS* using those functions, so I don't understand your answer.

Comment: Right, those are on the if statement. I didn't scroll to the right. This code looks like it's good to go then.

Comment: One should be able to put anything inside the database and it would be fine. You only have to worry about that stuff when outputting data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work great as long as you are using the important functions such as real escape and validate url nd email.
keep it up

Thnx